# URL is changed to http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF after importing project from Eclipse to NetBeans

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My JSF2.0 web initially designed over Eclipse Indigo. After some point of time I realised that NetBeans is more powerful for web dev as it was highlighting the xhtml page along with all the xhtml validation at once. So finally I imported the project to NetBeans 7.3. Everything goes good but when I run it here, I noticed that URL is changed to `http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF`.

Where I need to mention the URL? I am running my web in Glassfish v3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to adjust the context root.

Check the netbeans kb article here [project-setup-existing-sources](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#existing-web-sources)

```
10.(Optional) Adjust the context path. By default, the context path is based on the project name.
```

Also check glassfish-web.xml

For example, the glassfish-web.xml file for the hello1 application specifies the following context root:

```
<context-root>/hello1</context-root>
```

See also:

- https://sites.google.com/site/netbeansscsni/Home/section-4--java-ee-web-development/4-1-describe-how-to-create-a-netbeans-project-from-the-source-code-of-an-existing-web-application